# Using rsync to back up a remote computer through a reverse ssh link

Tags: networking, ssh, rsync, find, timestamp

I can rsync to my remote computer, but cannot rsync from my remote computer - it doesn't seem to exchange a file list in that direction, so it tries to transfer all of a huge number of files rather than update just the ones that have changed are that are new.

The setup is a bit complicated. I have a remote computer behind a firewall and need to exchange files with that computer from my home computer.  The home computer doesn't have a permanent IP address, so I'm using `noip` to bounce the reverse ssh to whatever my home computer's current IP address is. The reverse ssh command my remote computer is running is:

```
autossh -g -R 45678:localhost:22 me@noip.net
```

On my home computer, I'm running the `noip2` program that tells noip.net to bounce port 45678 to my home computer.

On my home computer, I can synchronize my documents folder to my remote computer using:

```
rsync -navzu --stats -e "ssh -p 45678" --delete /home/me/Documents/ me@localhost:/home/me/Documents
```

That works fine. Only documents that are new or have been updated are transferred and the remote computer is made up-to-date.

However, when I try to reverse this to update home home computer from the remote computer with the following, it doesn't work:

```
rsync -navzu --stats -e "ssh -p 45678" --delete me@localhost:/home/me/Documents/ /home/me/Documents
```

rsync sees *none* of the files in Documents on my home computer and tries to transfer every file, on a dry run.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like I found an answer to my question, though the problem isn't what I thought it was.

I had a chance to take a closer look at what files rsync was trying to transfer.  Turns out it wasn't every file, but the vast majority.  Apparently, when the remote filesystem was created, a switch wasn't used to insure that the date-time stamp was preserved.  As a result, all the files were copied over with a date-time stamp of the date on which the files were created on the remote system.  Only files that have been updated since then had different time-stamps.  So, when rsync tries to update the local system from the remote one, it tries to copy almost all files because they have a newer timestamp on the remote system than on the local system.

So, the solution for fixing this is to use touch to put the correct timestamps on the remote system.  I'm not very familiar with the linux shell, so there's probably a much more elegant solution, but here's what worked for me:

**#1: Mount remote file system locally:**

```
sshfs -p 45678 me@localhost:/ ./mntpt/
```

**#2: Put the following shell script on the remote file system and run it:**

```
#!/bin/bash
find * -newermt "2014-04-22" ! -newermt "2014-04-23" | while read f; 
do
 touch "$f" -c -m -r "/home/me/Documents/$f"
done
```

The above still takes a long time to run, but almost certainly not as long as trying to back up all the files through a fairly slow connection.  I tried various one-line shell command solutions instead of a script, but found no way to reference the file list twice in the touch command.